# Why the last circle is bolder than others?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have three circle svg elements with same `stroke-width`, but the last one is bolder.
Here is the svg code:

```
<div>
    <svg width="114" height="114">
        <circle stroke="#6d86c7" stroke-dashoffset="62.02111948377269" stroke-dasharray="62.02111948377269,258.4213311823862" r="51" cx="50%" cy="50%"></circle>
        <circle stroke="#e05c5c" stroke-dashoffset="165.38965195672716" stroke-dasharray="103.36853247295448,217.07391819320443" r="51" cx="50%" cy="50%"></circle>
        <circle stroke="#f6a623" stroke-dashoffset="320.4424506661589" stroke-dasharray="155.05279870943173" r="51" cx="50%" cy="50%"></circle>
    </svg>
</div>
```

And the result look like this:

[image: the result look like this].

It seems like the last one always gets bolder...

Comment: Please share here the svg code.

Comment: @vlk it's in the first picture. thanks

Comment: Can you please share the code in a form such as codepen.io or jsfiddle.net. It would make it way easier to diagnose the problem, otherwise we will have to copy down your code, and that is a pain.

Comment: @LukeSheltraw It' s generated by js .I will add it later ,sorry.

Comment: @GZXue, Ok but isn't how this site works, please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . You must share relevant code directly on stack overflow question. We're talking about an svg with 3 circle, what's the difficult on share it?

Comment: All the same size for me (in Chrome). What browser and version are you using ? Sure you don't have any extra css affecting it ?

Comment: @GZXue see this http://jsfiddle.net/4Lga5sco/

Comment: @lan chrome version 59.0.3071.71

Comment: @Amal thanks! you are right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because all three circles have a white `fill`.  As each one is drawn, the white fill overwrites the inside part of the stroke of the previous circles.  Remember that strokes are drawn so that they are half inside, and half outside, the circle.

The solution is to only put the white fill on the first of the three circles.

```css
#first circle {
  stroke-width: 4px;
  fill: none;
}

#first circle:nth-child(1) {
  fill: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
  <svg width="114" height="114">
    <circle stroke="#6d86c7" stroke-dashoffset="62.02111948377269" stroke-dasharray="62.02111948377269,258.42133118 23862" r="51" cx="50%" cy="50%"></circle>
    <circle stroke="#e05c5c" stroke-dashoffset="165.38965195672716" stroke-dasharray="103.36853247295448,217.07391819320443" r="51" cx="50%" cy="50%"></circle>
    <circle stroke="#f6a623" stroke-dashoffset="320.4424506661589" stroke-dasharray="155.05279870943173,165.38965195672712" r="51" cx="50%" cy="50%"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```